Question about scaling when printing image with GDI+
It seems that information about resolution and DPI that I get from printer are not correct.
I want the picture that I send to the printer is always maximized in width.
Horizontal resolution for example PNG file is 386 pixels, and DPI is 96, math says width is 4.02 inches or 10.21 cm.
When I send picture to the Microsoft Print to PDF printer in Windows, the procedure GetDeviceCaps(hdc_print, HORZRES) returns 5100 pixels, and DPI is 600. It does not matter if I request DPI with GetDeviceCaps(hdc_print, LOGPIXELSX) or graphics.GetDpiX(), result is always the same 600.
5100 pixels with 600 DPI resulting in paper width 8.5 inches, which is Letter paper format.
To get scaling value it is 8.5/4.02 and that is 2.1144. So the image width sent to the printer is 816 pixels.
Problem is when I use DrawImage(), image is not maximized in width. It is about 4% smaller. So the image resolution should be 849 pixels. To adjust printer resolution to to the pixels image value, the actual resolution of the printer with 600 DPI should be 5304 pixels.
When I send image to the real printer, in my case it is HP, that percentage is different, resolution should be increased to 4.2 percent. I assume that percentage value is changing with printer manufacturer and the model.
So, I used IrfanView to print that image and it is printed perfectly. Print preview shows paper is Letter format and DPI is 600. Also, since image is black and white, when I print image with IrfanView there is no interpolation. Pixels are squared, no matter it is sent to the virtual printer or physical. I have managed to get print without interpolation when I send it to the PDF printer, and when scaling resolution is corrected. If I just use scaling value, then interpolation is active.
What am I missing to get the real scaling value for correct print? And how to disable scaling when printing?

@KJ, I did not want to use XPS printing, because it says on Microsoft webpage that it is not supported and could be unavailable in the future. Or do you suggest to try to print image to Microsoft XPS Document Writer? I have sent image to the real printer and the problem is the same, just percentage is a little bit different.
